# Is $f(x) = \log_x a$ a known function?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

It might be a weird question but is this a known function?
$$f(x) = \log_x a$$
I've never seen it before.

Comment: $\log_{x}(a)=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(x)}$.

Comment: Known in what sense? I've seen this expression (sometimes with specific numbers in place of $a,$ but not always) in college algebra and precalculus exponential/logarithm exercises, and I've seen it in calculus texts where students are asked to differentiate it. But outside of artificial situations like these, it doesn't show up very often in mathematical or scientific discourse.

Comment: That's probably because people prefer to write it in the form $\frac{\log a}{\log x}$. The reciprocal logarithm $\frac{1}{\log x}$ occurs in various places of mathematics (such as in describing the asymptotic density of prime numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I've never seen it before".
Mathematicians almost never use logarithms to base other than $e$.  Whenever such thing comes up, they immediately write it in terms of the natural logarithm.

$$
x = 2^y\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y=\log_2 x 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y = \frac{\log x}{\log 2}
$$
where "$\log$" denotes the natural logarithm.  In fact,
mathematicans probably leave out the middle step, and merely write:

$$
x = 2^y\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y = \frac{\log x}{\log 2} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's known. Usually the parameter $a$ is required to be a positive real number and the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$. $f(x)$ is then the one and only real number $y$ such that $x^y=a$.